# What regex can I use to get the domain name from a url in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to construct a regex to extract a domain given a url.

for:

```
http://www.abc.google.com/
http://abc.google.com/
https://www.abc.google.com/
http://abc.google.com/
```

should give:

```
abc.google.com
```

Comment: In terms of DNS, `www.example.com` does not necessarily have to point to the same machine as `example.com`.

Comment: www.example.com and example.com couldbe two different sites?

Comment: Sure they can. It's a convention not to do that, but nothing prevents you from setting distinct A records on those two domains in DNS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
URI.parse('http://www.abc.google.com/').host
#=> "www.abc.google.com"
```

Not a regex, but probably more robust then anything we come up with here.

```
URI.parse('http://www.abc.google.com/').host.gsub(/^www\./, '')
```

If you want to remove the `www.` as well this will work without raising any errors if the `www.` is not there.

Comment: i want to remove the www. too

Comment: This isn't the most robust solution. Regex can be more reliable, especially if people forget to include "http" in the URI.

Comment: It's pretty robust if you can assume data integrity, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about ruby but this regex pattern gives you the last 3 parts of the url excluding the trailing slash with a minumum of 2 characters per part.

```
([\w-]{2,}\.[\w-]{2,}\.[\w-]{2,})/$
```

Comment: Should be `([\w-]{2,}\.[\w-]{2,}\.[\w-]{2,})\/$`. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to use the [domain_name gem](https://github.com/knu/ruby-domain_name) for this kind of work. From the README:

```
require "domain_name"
host = DomainName("a.b.example.co.uk")
host.domain         #=> "example.co.uk"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little bit vague. Can you give a precise specification of what it is *exactly* that you want to do? (Preferable with a testsuite.) Right now, all your question says is that you want a method that always returns `'abc.google.com'`. That's easy:

```
def extract_domain
  return 'abc.google.com'
end
```

But that's probably not what you meant …

Also, you say that you need a `Regexp`. Why? What's wrong with, for example, using the `URI` class? After all, parsing and manipulating URIs is *exactly* what it was made for!

```
require 'uri'

URI.parse('https://abc.google.com/').host # => 'abc.google.com'
```

And lastly, you say you are "*trying to extract a domain*", but you never specify what you *mean* by "domain". It looks you are sometimes meaning the FQDN and sometimes randomly dropping parts of the FQDN, but according to what rules? For example, for the FQDN `abc.google.com`, the domain name is `google.com` and the host name is `abc`, but you want it to return `abc.google.com` which is not just the domain name but the *full* FQDN. Why?

Comment: i might have framed the qn wrongly. what am trying to do is just remove the leading "http://www." and evering thing after .com

so given "http://www.google.com/" should give google.com
"http://www.abc.google.com/" should return abc.google.com

Comment: Why do you want to get abc.google.com for http://abc.google.com/ but google.com for http://www.google.com/ ? What makes the 'www' special? It is just a convention that http-servers usually are on the host named www but it don't have to be that way.

Comment: yeah. i use a webservice which strips of http and www part of the sitename. to compare the results i need to do the same before doing it